# Terminal script to group files into folders

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory of files. I want to group them together in batches into n directories.

So...

"MyFolder" has files A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

I want to put them in to, say, 3 batches... batched like this:

```
Folder 1 - A, B, C, D

Folder 2 - E, F, G

Folder 3 - H, I, J
```

(and not like this... which is in only way I can work it out myself)

```
Folder 1 - A, D, G, J

Folder 2 - B, E, H

Folder 3 - C, F, I
```

Can anyone please advise me on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping people fix their code. Post yours and we can very likely help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the argument list (the only list available to POSIX shell without using advanced features from e.g. bash).  Note the caveat; a sufficiently large number of files will not fit into the argument buffer.  Also note that Stack Overflow incorrectly assumes `$#` (the length of the argument list) begins a comment, so the coloring is a bit off.

```
#!/bin/sh

num_folders=3   # default to 3 directories
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  num_folders=$1
  shift
fi

# put all files into "argument" list
# (CAVEAT: this won't work on a dir with a LOT of files)
set - *

batch=$(( $# / $num_folders ))      # files per folder
remainder=$(( $# % $num_folders ))  # folders to get an "extra" file

i=1
while [ $i -le $num_folders ]; do

  mkdir "Folder $i"
  if [ $i -le $remainder ]
    then j=0
    else j=1
  fi

  while [ $j -le $batch ]; do
    mv "$1" "Folder $i"
    shift
    j=$(( $j + 1 ))
  done

  i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Here is this script in action (I'm using `#` as a prompt to trigger a different color for commands vs output):

```perl
# touch A B C D E F G H I J
# ls *
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
# sh ../batch-n.sh 3
# ls *
Folder 1:
A  B  C  D

Folder 2:
E  F  G

Folder 3:
H  I  J
```

Here's what happens when n=`4`

```
# touch A B C D E F G H I J
# ls *
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
# sh ../batch-n.sh 4
# ls *
Folder 1:
A  B  C

Folder 2:
D  E  F

Folder 3:
G  H

Folder 4:
I  J
```

I put this code in the parent directory (I therefore invoked it as `../batch-n.sh`) because it would otherwise file itself.  This will work just fine with files that have spaces in it, so long as they all fit into a single command (if `ls *` can't run, neither can this script).

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
mkdir /tmp/so
cd /tmp/so
touch {A..Z} # create 26 files
```

Simplest thing that would work:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae7b1d7d459b5ee)</kbd>**

```
for a in Folder\ {1..8}; do mkdir -pv "$a"; read z y x w; mv -v "$z" "$y" "$x" "$w" "$a/"; done < <(ls ? | xargs -n4)
```

Or, prettier:

```
for a in Folder\ {1..8}; 
do mkdir -pv "$a"
   read z y x w
   mv -v "$z" "$y" "$x" "$w" "$a/"
done < <(ls ? | xargs -n4)
```

Alternatively, (slightly better with names containing whitespace)

```
for a in Folder\ {1..8}; do mkdir -pv "$a"; read z && read y && read x && read w; mv -v "$z" "$y" "$x" "$w" "$a/"; done < <(ls ?)
```

Comment: Very clever logic (bravo on the concision!), but do note that you've got several bashisms in this code that will not work in all POSIX shells.  Specifically, the dotdot syntax (`{A..Z}` and `{1..8}`) and command substitution (`<(command)`) do not exist in shells that are simpler than bash.  The Ubuntu wiki has [a nice guide on correcting bashisms](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#I_am_a_developer._How_can_I_avoid_this_problem_in_future.3F) if you're interested.

Comment: I'm aware of the bashisms. Thanks for noting it though in case others don't know !